# Getting ClassNotFoundException on loading Android application

Tags: android, class, exception

I have an Android app uploaded on to the market.The app has a class that is to be loaded at startup. I have used some global variables in the class

Problem is that my developer console is showing me errors of ClassNotFoundException for this particular class. However, when I test on various handsets, I don't get any error, but this is happening on quite of few handsets as I can see the error frequently in the developer console

Following is the error log. The name of the class is MyApp

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.test.app.MyApp:      
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.app.MyApp in loader  
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.test.app-1/pkg.apk]
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:481)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3882)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1089)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4369)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:846)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.app.MyApp in loader    
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/com.test.app-1/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:972)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:472)
```

Following is the snapshot of the Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.app"
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
android:versionCode="30"
android:versionName="1.5.3">
<application android:name = "MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon"      
android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

<activity android:name=".GamesWorld"
android:label="@string/app_name">            
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

give to **.Myapp**

```
<application android:name = ".MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

Comment: MyApp is not an Activity it is an class that extends Application, you should read the error carefully and then give your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems ou have not set the "launcher" in your  activity inside application application

```
    <activity
       android:name=".GamesWorld"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I do have a launcher, its just that I didn't paste the entire Manifest :-)

Answer (score 0):

put a `.` before `MyApp` in the  manifest.  You have `<activity android:name=".GamesWorld"`
 and `<application android:name = "MyApp"`

it should be:

`<application android:name = ".MyApp"`

Comment: I actually had .MyApp given earlier, I too suspected this and changed it to just MyApp. But the error still exists